# Dynamically updating EC2 Security Groups on deploy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a number of node apis that run on elastic beanstalk.

We are configuring the load balancer and a number of other things using .config files in the ebextensions folder.

Is it possible to get the secruity id from the newly created security group when eb create is run and the api is pushed to elastic beanstalk and started then add it to an inbound rule on another security group that already exists.

Would like to be able to have it all scripted so when we terminate and re create the rules will be re created.

Comment: Yes, its possible. You have to program this in your ebextentions.

Comment: Do you know how? struggling to find examples of it being done